# Method returning undefined even though fetch succeeds?

Tags: reactjs, return, components, fetch, undefined

I have two components, Client and App, and a fetch function. App is the child component of Client. I want to update Client's state using the return value from the method App calls. However, Client's state response is undefined after the fetch. I'm not sure why this code does not work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';  

function post(user, token, data){
  console.log('fetching...')
  fetch(`/project`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic '+ btoa(user+':'+token),
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }).then(r => {
      if (!r.ok)
        throw Error(r.status);
      r.json().then(r => {return(r)});
  }).catch(error => {throw Error(error)})
}

class Client extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: '',
      token: '111',
      project: {'project':'demo'},
      response: {},
    };

    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
  };


  updateState(){
    const { user, token, project } = this.state;
    post(user, token, project).then(text => this.setState({ response: text 
  }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <App updateState={this.updateState}/>
    )
  }
}

class App extends Component {      
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <button onClick={ () => {
             this.props.updateState()} }>Fetch Project</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: I changed my post() to this and it works :)

```
async function post(user, token, data){
  console.log('fetching...')
  const response = await fetch(`/project`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic '+ btoa(user+':'+token),
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }).catch(error => {throw Error(error)});

  if(!response.ok)
    throw Error(response.status);
  
  const obj = await response.json();
  return(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with promises, you can do something like this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
    async function post() {
      // fetch //
      return await fetch("https://hipsum.co/api/?type=hipster-centric");
    }

    class Client extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          response: "12"
        };
        this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
      }

      async updateState(res) {
        const text = await res().then(res => res.text());
        this.setState({ response: text });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <>
            {this.state.response}
            <App updateState={this.updateState} />
          </>
        );
      }
    }

    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                this.props.updateState(post);
              }}
            >
              Fetch
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Client;
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-tree-70ou8?file=/src/App.js:0-851)

Comment: I followed your advice, but response still seems to be undefined after the fetch. I checked that fetch was returning the proper string, but when I print out const text in the updateState method, it is undefined. I updated my code above to reflect the changes.

Comment: @hao hm, that's strange, your code seems correct. Maybe your POST call is not supposed to return anything. `console.log(r.clone().text())` will return a promise, you shouldn't be seeing any output. To debug the the response, you do `r.text().then(r=>console.log(r))`

Comment: console.log(r.clone().text()) prints the promise to the console. r.text().then(r=>console.log(r)) prints the object. When I try to return that object instead of printing it to the console, it comes out as undefined in the updateState method. I tried setting onClick=updateState() and then calling the post function inside updateState but still no luck.

Comment: @hao what kinds of objects did you get? If you return an actual string, can you get it in your updateState method?

Comment: `r.text().then(r=>console.log(r))` prints this in the console : `{"graph": [["node1", "node2"]], "features": {"feature1": ["opt1", "opt2"], "feature2": ["opt1", "opt2"]}}`. I also tried to cast and return this object as a string but it shows up as undefined in updateState(). I think something is wrong with my return.  If I remove the async and await from the post function, the fetch().then() is printed after my print statement in updateState() even though I await for fetch in updateState().

Comment: @hao maybe do the error handling in your updateState function? edit: https://jsfiddle.net/gwa8pmyq/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216346/discussion-between-hao-and-toxnyc).

Answer (score 0):

It will be nice to know all the code for the fetch function but I think the problem is mostly here:

```
this.props.updateState(post())
```

That call is synchronous and the fetching process isn't. You need a better approach with await or promises or a callback.